# 1660 TI, laptop HDMI out 4K @ 144hz?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've got a new laptop for work and I'm essentially using it like a desktop. I've used the USB-C to DP to connect one 1920x1080 display at 60hz which is fine. My main display is a 4K 144hz panel and I was hoping to utilise that refresh rate.

`xrandr`

returns the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 11120 x 3840, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected 2160x3840+3840+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 267mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 5120x2880+6000+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    30.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440    120.00  
   1920x1080    119.88    60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    23.98  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

As you can see, the HDMI input seems to only support 60hz at 4K resolution.

I'm using [this exact cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B083C25YF1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

Which should be capable of 4K@144hz.

I've tried both of my monitors HDMI ports just in case one is rated at 60hz or something.

My 4K monitor is [this.](https://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-27GN950-B)

I don't suppose there's anything else I can try other than trying to set it manually in the CLI and trying different nVidia drivers?

Comment: I would take the title of that cable listing with a pinch of salt. Regardless, 120Hz would be the minimum you would expect to show, however now that you mention _all_ devices needing to support these bandwidths I do wonder if the laptop's HDMI out even supports higher than 60Hz. I'll have to do some digging into the specs.

Comment: @Nmath Turns out it's a HDMI 2.0 port. 4K@60Hz is the maximum. You were right about not all devices being up to par. No matter, I'll only be in an IDE for work anyway! Save the 144Hz for gaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your answers are contained in the links you already provided.

The tech specs on cable you linked describes a maximum bandwidth of 4K@120Hz.

The tech specs on the monitor itself advertise a maximum bandwidth over the HDMI port at 3840 x 2160 (4K) at 60Hz.

It is very clear from the technical specifications of both items that you will not be able to achieve 4K@144Hz over HDMI.

The monitor's tech specs also give several qualifications that must be met in order to achieve 4K@144Hz:

- You must use DisplayPort.
- You must turn on DSC.
- The minimum required GPU is NVIDIA RTX16/20 series or AMD RX5500 or higher graphics card.

Comment: Selected as the answer. As per the comments, I found out about the laptop's HDMI port being a 2.0 port, that right there stops my ability to use anything over 60Hz. Plus as you've just pointed out, my monitor itself only supports 4K 60Hz on its HDMI ports. Thanks. I'll save the 144Hz for my gaming PC. Which you'll never guess, is connected via DP ;).